# How to provision Using t2 micro vm @ AWS using Juju

Tags: server, juju, aws, continuous-deployment

Currently I provision vms at AWS using Juju deploy mysql and setup environment are medium size vms. How can I setup/run using t2 micro vms at AWS?  What are commands?  Here are what I used currently..

```
juju bootstrap -e juju03
juju deploy juju-gui
juju expose juju-gui
juju deploy wordpress
juju deploy mysql
juju add-relation wordpress mysql
juju status
juju expose wordpress
```

Juju version I am using is 2.0beta7.xenial-amd64.

Comment: Thanks but hows about bootstrap command to create environment?  Like this???
juju-1 bootstrap -e juju03 --constraints 'instance-type=t2.micro'